# Send email in jenkins multiple times in a single job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I want to send email 2 times in a single job , one before starting the build and one after the build .

I tried to do that with editable email plugin but it is not allowing me to configure it second time in the job .

Any way to achieve this ?

Thanks ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add *Editable Email Notification* as a **post-build action** and Add a *Before Build* trigger.

You have to click on "Advanced" -> "Add Trigger" -> "Before Build" to do this.

[image: Screenshot of the Before Build Trigger]

If you have multiple triggers and want different emails or recipients, you can customize the email tje "Advanced..." section of the trigger:

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced section of the Before Build Trigger]

Comment: Thanks ,  my bad i was trying to add the plugin again rather than adding a trigger

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)